# How to place text centered on the player? XNA

Tags: c#, vector

As I can make a text of the size of this, it is centered taking reference of the player?

Right now the following happens:

[image]

I want:

[image]

code:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(Font, player.Name, new Vector2(player.position.X, player.position.Y - 12), Color.White);
```

PS: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

[SpriteFont.MeasureString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464128(v=xnagamestudio.30).aspx) returns

> The height and width, in pixels, of text, when it is rendered.

As such, positioning the text at the center.x - half text width should center the text:

```
float xOffset = player.position.X + (player.width / 2) - 
(Font.MeasureString(player.Name).X / 2);

spriteBatch.DrawString(Font, player.Name, new Vector2(xOffset, 
player.position.Y - 12), Color.White);
```

Comment: I have a problem with the SpriteFont.MeasureString. "an object reference is required for the non-static field, methog or property"

Comment: Your spritefont seems to be called 'Font'

Comment: You would do `Font.MeasureString(string)` instead. Corrected the code.

Comment: Now the problem is  ->   Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'Vector2'

Comment: `MeasureString` returns a vector2. Take the x component of it. `Font.MeasureString(player.Name).X`

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand.

Comment: @SrOsito Just use his updated code. In any case, it's your job to adapt the answer given to work with your variables and types.

Comment: Error: Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2' to 'float'  [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/X25ZcNvA)

Comment: Line 73: Change Vector2 to float.